# Laravel queue - running as a daemon

Tags: php, laravel-4, queue, beanstalkd

I am trying to setup Laravel beanstalkd queue as mentioned [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queues#daemon-queue-worker). I need to run the queue handler as a daemon.

Trying to run the command: **php artisan queue:work --daemon**.

But looks like 'deamon' command is not defined for queue:work

```
>php artisan queue:work --help
Usage:
 queue:work [--queue[="..."]] [--delay[="..."]] [--force] [--        memory[="..."]] [--sleep[="..."]] [--tries[="..."]] [connection]

Arguments:
 connection            The name of connection

Options:
 --queue               The queue to listen on
 --delay               Amount of time to delay failed jobs (default: 0)
 --force               Force the worker to run even in maintenance mode
 --memory              The memory limit in megabytes (default: 128)
 --sleep               Number of seconds to sleep when no job is     available (default: 3)
 --tries               Number of times to attempt a job before logging it     failed (default: 0)
 --help (-h)           Display this help message.
 --quiet (-q)          Do not output any message.
 --verbose (-v|vv|vvv) Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal     output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug
 --version (-V)        Display this application version.
 --ansi                Force ANSI output.
 --no-ansi             Disable ANSI output.
 --no-interaction (-n) Do not ask any interactive question.
 --env                 The environment the command should run under
```

I am using Larvel 4

```
 >php artisan --version

 Laravel Framework version 4.1.31
```

Any idea on why 'daemon' attribute is missing for queue:work command in my setup?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Daemon option is available for Laravel 4.2+. 
Update laravel to 4.2 and you'll have that option by running `composer update`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. One more doubt: I need to be able to run "php artisan queue:work --daemon" and close the terminal and want the daemon keep running in background.   But command does not return.  Is it possible to make this run in background?

Comment: @Krishna Shetty You should look into supervisord for processing your jobs.